# Out of date plugins not showing ugrade link

Tags: plugins

I recently noticed that my site is no longer showing the upgrade links for out of date plugins.

On my staging site I've upgraded to the latest version of WordPress (5.2.2) and upgraded to the latest version of the theme. Site and local cache have been cleared.

I've deactivated all plugins except for one I know needs to be upgraded (Backup Guard). I've also installed the WP-Cron Events plugin and run wp_update_plugins() action manually.

So far none of these have resolved the issue. I'm not sure what to do next.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Kym.

Comment: "Site and local cache have been cleared." - does that include the transients? Look for '_site_transient_update_plugins' or similar in the wp-options table which should contains timestamp and state from the latest update. If you can't find the problem there then you'll probably have to add trace to wp_update_plugins temporarily to work out what's going wrong, e.g. dump out the response you get from the plugin update server, or work out where in the function it's aborting if it's not getting that far.

Comment: Thanks Rup - I traced the error all the way down to the update_option function but I don't have enough WP experience to progress from here. I'll need to get some external help.

Answer (score 0):

Run this SQL query on your site's WordPress database

```
update wp_options set option_value='' where option_name='_site_transient_update_plugins';
```

This will force WordPress to check for plugin updates.

Comment: Thanks Awais - I deleted the option but unfortunately nothing has changed. I have traced the error back to the update_option() function but I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't know enough to keep going so I'll contract someone to fix it.

Comment: Maybe the plugin that you want to update is a premium plugin which needs a licence to activate the update feature.

Comment: I have about 32 plugins installed - about half of them need updating but the upgrade link is not being displayed. One plugin is displaying the upgrade link - Visual Composer that came with the theme. It requires a licence. When I upgrade the theme I can update Visual Composer via the theme plugin screen. However, all the rest can not be upgraded. Not sure what's going on.